# How to convert columns having char datatype with numeric values to numeric datatype

Tags: r

```
    $Budget(chr)"3,000.00", "2,000.00", "2,000.00"...  
    $Impressions(int) 0, 0, 0, 0...  
    $Interactions(int) 0, 0, 0...  
    $Interaction.Rate(chr) "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%"...  
    $Avg..Cost (dbl) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...  
    $Cost(chr) "0", "0", "0", "0"...  
    $Clicks(int) 0, 0, 0, 0...  
    $CTR(chr) "0.00%", "0.00%", "0.00%"...
```

I have some columns.All of them have numeric values but when I imported them in R they appeared to be of a character data type.I want to convert these character to integer and also remove % sign from the columns that have them.

```
    mData=mData %>%
    mutate(Budget=as.numeric(Budget),  
    Interaction.Rate=as.numeric(gsub("%","",Interaction.Rate)),  
    Cost=as.numeric(Cost),  
    CTR=as.numeric(gsub("%","",CTR)))
```

I tried doing this but no result instead it gives me error:

> Warning message: In eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : NAs
>   introduced by coercion

Can anyone help me out with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a data frame column to numeric type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type)

Comment: You need to remove the comma from the `Budget`-column as well with `gsub`. Another possibility is to use the `parse_number`-function from the `readr`-package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` to convert them back to `numeric`.

```
transform(mData, Budget= as.numeric(Budget), Interaction.Rate = as.numeric(nteraction.Rate), ...)
```

To remove `,` and `%` use `gsub` (got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129554/in-r-remove-commas-from-a-field-and-have-the-modified-field-remain-part-of-the))

```
 mData$Budget<- as.numeric(gsub("," ,"" ,mData$Budget))
```