# how to add or subtract comma separated numbers in r?

Tags: r

How to perform a calculation on numbers that are comma separated. For example

```
result <- 10,000 + 5,000 + 60,000
```

gives the error

> Error: unexpected ',' in "result <- 10,"

Comment: Are your numeric columns structured this way (i.e. with commas)? or are you asking how to perform calculations with dollar representation of numbers in R?

Comment: You have to remove commas or else R does not view it as a numeric column. You can use gsub(',', '',df$column_name) to get rid of commas.

Answer (score 1):

While using `gsub` and `format` functionality will certainly do the trick, another alternative is to use some of `tidyverse` packages. The code is arguably easier to read and interpret than `gsub`:

```
library( readr )
library( scales )
comma( parse_number("10,000") + parse_number("5,000") + parse_number("60,000") )
# [1] "75,000"
```

Comment: the procedure may become tedious when there are many numbers, say 30 or 40

Comment: How are your numbers stored? `parse_number` works correctly on vectors. Consider `parse_number(v)`, where `v` is a vector that contains your 30-40 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove commas, do your math, and then add them back.  Documentation:

[In R: remove commas from a field AND have the modified field remain part of the dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129554/in-r-remove-commas-from-a-field-and-have-the-modified-field-remain-part-of-the)

[Comma separator for numbers in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838774/comma-separator-for-numbers-in-r)

Comment: This suppose to be a comment rather than a answer .